# MySQL: Add sequence column based on another field

Tags: php, mysql, sequence

I'm working on some legacy code/database, and need to add a field to the database which will record a sequence number related to that (foreign) id.

Example table data (current):

```
ID     ACCOUNT     some_other_stuff
1      1           ...
2      1           ...
3      1           ...
4      2           ...
5      2           ...
6      1           ...
```

I need to add a sequenceid column which increments separately for each account, achieving:

```
ID     ACCOUNT     SEQ     some_other_stuff
1      1           1       ...
2      1           2       ...
3      1           3       ...
4      2           1       ...
5      2           2       ...
6      1           4       ...
```

Note that the sequence is related to account.

Is there a way I can achieve this in SQL, or do I resort to a PHP script to do the job for me?

TIA,
Kev

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work but is probably slow:

```
CREATE temporary table seq ( id int, seq int);
INSERT INTO seq ( id, seq )
    SELECT id, 
      (SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM test c 
      WHERE c.id < test.id AND c.account = test.account) as seq 
    FROM test;

UPDATE test INNER join seq ON test.id = seq.id SET test.seq = seq.seq;
```

I have called the table 'test'; obviously that needs to be set correctly. You have to use a temporary table because MySQL will not let you use a subselect from the same table you are updating.

Answer (score 13):

Create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_mytable_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      DECLARE nseq INT;
      SELECT  COALESCE(MAX(seq), 0) + 1
      INTO    nseq
      FROM    mytable
      WHERE   account = NEW.account;
      SET NEW.seq = nseq;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but in the end I went for the temporary table solution above.

Comment: For anyone having problems with confusing errors, see here about using delimiters in the trigger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814153/error-in-your-sql-syntax-creating-mysql-trigger

Answer (score 10):

The question is tagged as "mysql", so yes, MySQL's auto_increment can create groupwise sequential ids.
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html:

> For **MyISAM** and **BDB** tables you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as `MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix`. This is useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.

edit: example php script (using [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo), but it's the same game with the [php-mysql](http://docs.php.net/mysql) module)

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=...;dbname=...', '...', '...'); 
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

// example table
$pdo->exec(
  'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Foo (
    id int auto_increment,
    account int,
    someotherstuff varchar(32),
    primary key(account,id)
  ) engine=MyIsam'
);
// insert example data
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO Foo (account,someotherstuff) VALUES (?,?)');
$stmt->execute(array(1, '1a'));
$stmt->execute(array(1, '1b'));
$stmt->execute(array(1, '1c'));
$stmt->execute(array(2, '2a'));
$stmt->execute(array(2, '2b'));
$stmt->execute(array(1, '1d'));
unset($stmt);

// query data
foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT account,id,someotherstuff FROM Foo') as $row ) {
  echo $row['account'], ' ', $row['id'], ' ', $row['someotherstuff'], "\n";
}
```

prints

```
1 1 1a
1 2 1b
1 3 1c
2 1 2a
2 2 2b
1 4 1d
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry - I should have specified tables are innoDB. I eventually went for the temp tables solution below, but appreciate the input! Cheers!

Comment: Nice Solution. This is the correct answer. works great.