# error in your SQL syntax creating MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, innodb

I try create trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `aster_users2` after
update ON `aster_users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  update event set flag=1 where
id=1; END;
```

but got next error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end' at line 6

have suggestion to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try removing the semi-colons from your statements.

If you'd like to keep your semi-colons,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `aster_users2` after
update ON `aster_users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  update event set flag=1 where
id=1;  
 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I've wasted around hour. Thanks

Comment: @bynu022 You have not wasted your hour, you have actually invested your hour by learning from your mistakes.

Answer (score 10):

You can either:

- drop `BEGIN` and `END` (is only possible when there's a single statement in the body):

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER `aster_users2` after
  update ON `aster_users` FOR EACH ROW
  update event set flag=1 where id=1;
  ```

  or
- add the DELIMITER specifier for the entire `CREATE TRIGGER` statement:

  ```
  DELIMITER |
  CREATE TRIGGER `aster_users2` after
  update ON `aster_users` FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    update event set flag=1 where id=1;  
  END|
  DELIMITER ;
  ```

  Note the second `DELIMITER`, which restores the default statement delimiter.

**EDIT** – Explanation:

Generally you are using `;` to delimit statements. But when it comes to compound statements like `CREATE TRIGGER`, which use `BEGIN/END` and allow you to include multiple statements in their bodies, the parser needs a way to distinguish the delimiters between the body's statements from the delimiter after the entire compound statement.

Thus you need to either refrain somehow from using `;` inside the compound statement or tell the parser that the compound statement will use a different delimiter. The first option can also be achieved if you just drop `;` before `END`, like [@p.campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814153/error-in-your-sql-syntax-creating-mysql-trigger/5814208#5814208) has suggested.

Comment: The first variant is appropriate here.

Comment: I like this answer more than the accepted answer, because it explains this illogical trap designed into MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Delimiters should be used.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `aster_users2` AFTER
UPDATE ON `aster_users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE event
  SET
    flag = 1
  WHERE
    id = 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```