# More than one if clause for MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I want to reach something like that:

When a data inserted it will check a date column, compare it with current date and it will write something to another column. Example:

```
Today 27/08/2018
Date 27/08/2018
Result: Same Day

Today 27/08/2018
Date 26/08/2018
Result: Before Today

Today 27/08/2018
Date 28/08/2018
Result: After Today
```

I have tried this and does not work:

```
//CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_status_before_insert 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON tablex
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (NEW.date < CURDATE()) THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'Before Today'
  END IF

  IF (NEW.date = CURDATE()) THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'Same Day'
  END IF

  IF (NEW.date > CURDATE()) THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'After Today'
  END IF
END;//
```

phpmyadmin delimiter: //

Comment: Every statement must be terminated.

Answer (score 0):

[error in your SQL syntax creating MySQL trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814153/error-in-your-sql-syntax-creating-mysql-trigger)
@p.campbell 's answer solved the problem. I just deleted semi column and it worked.