# Resequencing a column with identifier in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sequencing

The following code works and creates a temporary table with a sequence number which is restarted for every new name:

```
with results as (select row_number() over (partition by name order BY name) as mytid,name from telephn_table)
select * from results order by name
```

My objective however is to insert the new sequence number permanently into the telephone table.
How do I transfer the new sequence number from the results table to the telephone table? I have come across the following for MySql but was not able to convert it to Postgresql.

[MySQL: Add sequence column based on another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600294/mysql-add-sequence-column-based-on-another-field)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

If memory serves, `row_number()` returns the number within its own partition. In other words, `row_number() over (partition by name order BY name)` would return 1 for each row except duplicates. You likely want `rank() over (order by name)` instead.

---

After a long discussion:

```
update telephn_table
set sid = rows.new_sid
from (select pkey,
             row_number() over (partition BY name) as new_sid,
             name
      from telephn_table
      ) as rows
where rows.pkey = telephn_table.pkey;
```

Comment: @Denis Thank you for the answer but unfortunately it did not address my question which was "How do I transfer the new sequence number from the results table to the telephone table?". As I stated in my OP the code I listed works to my satisfaction, I just don't know how to copy/transfer the seq no. into the telephone table from the results table.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you knew how to do that part... Just update the table: `update yourtable set tid = rows.tid from (select ...) as rows where rows.id = yourtable.id;`

Comment: @Denis Thanks again. If I understood you correctly (and please keep in mind I am a postgresql beginner) this is what I came up with:

Comment: update telephn_table set sid = rows.mytid from (with results as (select rank() over (partition by name order BY name) as mytid,name from telephn_table)
select * from results order by name) as rows where rows.name = telephn_table.name;

Comment: This results in the sid column having 1 in all rows. Note that changing from row_number() to rank() gave identical results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: update telephn_table set sid = rows.mytid from (with results as (select rank() over (order BY name) as mytid,name from telephn_table)
select * from results order by name) as rows where rows.tid = telephn_table.sid;

Comment: Probably more like this: `update telephn_table set sid = rows.new_sid from (select sid, rank() over (order BY name) as new_sid, name from telephn_table) as rows where rows.sid = telephn_table.sid;`. Btw: you really shouldn't be bothering to re-number your primary key. Doing so defeats the whole point in using a surrogate key in the first place.

Comment: @Denis. Thanks Denis, looks better but not there yet. 
The following table tells you story:
RESULT    SHOULD BE

"AW";180;1   "AW";180;1
"AY";179;2    "AY";179;1
"AZ";178;3    "AZ";178;1
"BA";290;4    "BA";290;1
"BA";362;4    "BA";362;2
"BB";77;6     "BB";77;1
"BB";174;6    "BB";174;2
"BC";385;8    "BC";385;1
"BC";357;8    "BC";357;2
"BC";56;8     "BC";56;3
"BD";56;11    "BD";56;1
"BD";140;11   "BD";140;2
"BE";357;13   "BE";357;1
"BE";385;13   "BE";385;2
"BE";423;13   "BE";423;3

Comment: Sorry Denis, the table formatting is awful. Should have two columns headed RESULTS and SHOULD BE. Essentially I am looking for a sequential numbering scheme within name. Each new name should start again from 1. Two entries for the same name should be numbered 1 and 2, and so forth.

Comment: In that case, `(partition by name)` was correct, as was using `row_number()` instead of `rank()`. But my above suggested query is incorrect: you need a primary key, else you won't be able to update your table properly! And then adjust the update query to join on `rows.pkey = telephn_table.pkey`. Also, no offense but it would help if you read the postgresql tutorial before asking any further questions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/tutorial.html. SO is not a place to crowd-source consulting work.

Comment: Thank you Denis for your help and advice and absolutely no offence taken

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKS! (See my OP link to a previous MySql link. In Postgresql it works without need for a temporary table)

alter table telephn_table add column tid integer default 0;
UPDATE telephn_table set tid=(SELECT count(*)+1 from telephn_table t where t.sid < telephn_table.sid and telephn_table.name=t.name)