# How auto-increment within a subset of the table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

To illustrate my problem I will use the analogy of authors and books.

I have 2 tables "author" and "books". Authors are unique and books are tied to a specific authors using a foreign key constraint.

I was wondering if it was possible to have a column called "booknum" in the "books" table that auto-increment within the subset of a single author. So if the table has 100 rows and im inserting the 4th book of an author it puts a 4 into the "booknum" column.

[image: db image]

For example if the books table had 6 rows:

```
id | authors_id | booknum | name

1  | 1          | 1       | "hello"

2  | 1          | 2       | "goodbye"

3  | 2          | 1       | "booktitle"

4  | 3          | 1       | "more title"

5  | 1          | 3       | "nametwo"

6  | 2          | 2       | "nameone"
```

Is this possible within mysql or do I need to go and check for the last created book and manually increment when I add a book?

Comment: This schema is not normalized. A book can have more authors. You need to keep books in separate table, and the relationship between the books and authors in another table.

Comment: possible dup of [auto_increment by group](http://stackoverflow.com/q/677542/), [MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT by group using InnoDB or alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9381734/)

Comment: @Pentium10 then the example i used was bad. In my case things(books) can only be tied to one thing(author) but there can be many things(books) for one thing(author).

Comment: You will have to manually increment __and__ decrement at every insert, update and delete.

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than images and a table dump for sample data (images are never a good stand-in for sample code). Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for samples. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER biBooks 
  BEFORE INSERT ON books 
  FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.booknum = (
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(booknum), 0) + 1 
      FROM books 
      WHERE authors_id = NEW.authors_id
  )
;
```

Comment: @outis: This is brilliant! However, I've started to notice a problem on a particularly busy table. If there's a lot of inserts in parallel, I get deadlocks. Is there any way around that?

Comment: ***This is not safe.***  I should never have suggested it.  Please ignore this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Single-table syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

Multiple-table syntax:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_references
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
```

For the single-table syntax, the **UPDATE** statement updates columns of existing rows in the named table with new values. The **SET** clause indicates which columns to modify and the values they should be given. Each value can be given as an expression, or the keyword **DEFAULT** to set a column explicitly to its default value. The **WHERE** clause, if given, specifies the conditions that identify which rows to update. With **no WHERE** clause, all rows are updated. If the **ORDER BY** clause is specified, the rows are updated in the order that is specified. The **LIMIT** clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be updated.

For the multiple-table syntax, **UPDATE** updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For multiple-table syntax, **ORDER BY** and **LIMIT** cannot be used.