How to generate unique grouped autoincrement document id's?
I need to make some tables which are able to auto-increment unique document names for each month of the year based on the date of each documnet type. I think it will be a good idea to make it as a generated stored column in a MySql table. Thailand uses the Buddhist calendar where you normally add 543 years to the Christian calendar (2024 becomes 2567) in this case I add 43 years as I only need the last digits of the year. I am then missing the last serial number to number which I cannot find a solution to after intense searching on the internet. I would think it should be found under grouping.
In this case, I am working with the invoices.
My table:
CREATE TABLE `tbl_0_invoices` (
  `invoice_date` date NOT NULL,
  `invoice_no` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(_utf8mb4'INV',(date_format(`invoice_date`,_utf8mb4'%y') + 43),date_format(`invoice_date`,_utf8mb4'%m'))) STORED;
  
 ALTER TABLE `tbl_0_invoices`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_no`);

I have not been able to find any documentation on the issue, even this kind of document identification is quite normal in Thailand.
I expect this output.



invoice_date
invoice_no




21/8/2567
INV6708-1


13/9/2567
INV6709-1


13/9/2567
INV6709-2


13/9/2567
INV6709-3


13/9/2567
INV6709-4


18/9/2567
INV6709-5


25/10/2567
INV6710-1


25/10/2567
INV6710-2


25/10/2567
INV6710-3


25/10/2567
INV6710-4


24/1/2568
INV6801-1




"I need to make some tables which are able to auto-increment unique document names for each month of the year based on the date of each documnet type"  You're fighting against the typical auto increment behavior that would give you a serially increasing value.  Does the increment really need to reset every month?  Could you live with INV-6708-1, INV-6708-2, INV-6709-3 where the serial incement is not reset every month?

MyISAM allowed you to create a multi-column primary key with grouped auto increment of the second column. This feature is not available in InnoDB. You may have to do what you want using an INSERT trigger.

You can't use an INSERT trigger either, because auto-increment values are not generated in a BEFORE trigger, but you can't modify columns in an AFTER trigger. Nor can you make a generated column expression that references an auto-increment value.

Beware, in a heavily parallel environment this requirement will cause bottlenecks.

@eric258 I cannot use the serial increment if it's not reset every month. A demand from the accounting company doing our reporting.

@Barmar Thanks, I have tried that by looking into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600294/mysql-add-sequence-column-based-on-another-field, the difference is that the base field (group) is also generated at insert, and not a selected value, so until now no success.

Use DATE_FORMAT(date, "%y%m") to get the numeric year & month in format: YYMM.
Use row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY date) to get the increment value w.r.t YYMM value.
So, this is simple string joining query.
and MySQL query should be:
select 
    DATE_FORMAT(cast(invoice_date as date), '%d/%m/%Y') as invoice_date,
    CONCAT("INV", 
        DATE_FORMAT(cast(invoice_date as date), "%y%m"),
        "-",
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(cast(invoice_date as date), "%y%m"))
    ) as invoice_no
from mySQLTable;

Check Result: db<>fiddle
Result as follows:


Thanks, it works fine. I have one comment and one question:

you can't string the date because 29th february will give a problem every 4th year, thats why 43 is added to the year only, which I did.
I am not sure how I implement this into my table, but i can always make an invoice id, and join the table with a view, is that the idea?


I don't understanding what you exactly want... Your question is resolved according to description and  this is a new issue, then create a separate ticket with proper dbfiddle data table @LasseStaalung
